# Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, UTC] and Timestamp

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timestamp

This is some part of datasetDataset

> 1. Ordered Quantity   Time Stamp  Medicine Name   Actual Price
>    14162 3   2020-10-17 10:06:33.790000+00:00    27699   263.82
>    15747 2   2020-10-28 09:14:46.690000+00:00    27699   175.88
>    24866 2   2020-12-27 14:16:26.259000+00:00    27699   175.88
>    25962 2   2021-01-03 18:35:04.337000+00:00    27699   175.88
>    29188 2   2021-01-28 08:17:40.975000+00:00    27699   175.88
>    29565 2   2021-02-02 04:15:58.496000+00:00    27699   175.88
>    30863 2   2021-02-09 07:19:44.897000+00:00    27699   175.88
>    33931 2   2021-03-02 03:39:52.087000+00:00    27699   175.88
>    35537 2   2021-03-13 15:19:58.131000+00:00    27699   175.88
>    37429 1   2021-03-27 05:15:31.772000+00:00    27699   87.94
>    47099 1   2021-05-03 07:16:10.483000+00:00    27699   87.94
>    49135 2   2021-05-09 08:03:35.300000+00:00    27699   175.88
>    66057 1   2021-07-07 07:50:21.414000+00:00    27699   87.94
>    67937 1   2021-07-13 06:44:20.875000+00:00    27699   87.94

`

```
  import pandas as pd
  data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
  data["Time Stamp"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Time Stamp"])
  t1 = pd.Timestamp("2020-06-01 00:00:00.054000+00:00")
  t2 = t1.date() + pd.DateOffset(months = 6)
  data[(data["Time Stamp"] > t1) & (data["Time Stamp"] < t2)]
`
```

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, UTC] and Timestamp

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

Instead of using `t2` in comparision use `t2.tz_localize('utc')`:

```
data[(data["Time Stamp"] > t1) & (data["Time Stamp"] < t2.tz_localize('utc'))]
```

OR

use `normalize()` method instead of `date()` method:

```
t2=t1.normalize() + pd.DateOffset(months = 6)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But is there any other way of adding time zone in this statement itself "t2 = t1.date() + pd.DateOffset(months = 6)"

Comment: @Anuvicleo  yes...updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**