# Python Tried everything. Still getting this error: TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")

Tags: python, time-series, sentiment-analysis

I hope you can help me with this issue, I've been having for a while. I keep getting this error no matter what i try:

This is the type as I know it:

```
tweets['post_date'] = pd.to_datetime(tweets['post_date'], unit='s')
tweets['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tweets['post_date'].apply(lambda date: date.date()))


tweets.head()
```

Output:

```
    post_date   body    ticker_symbol   date
19  2015-01-01 00:11:17 $UNP $ORCL $QCOM $MSFT $AAPL Top scoring mega ...   MSFT    2015-01-01
43  2015-01-01 00:55:58 http://StockAviator.com....Top penny stocks, N...   MSFT    2015-01-01
```

> 

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py in _validate_comparison_value(self, other)
    539             try:
--> 540                 self._check_compatible_with(other)
    541             except (TypeError, IncompatibleFrequency) as err:

13 frames
TypeError: Cannot compare tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

InvalidComparison                         Traceback (most recent call last)
InvalidComparison: 2015-01-01 12:00:00-05:00

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/invalid.py in invalid_comparison(left, right, op)
     32     else:
     33         typ = type(right).__name__
---> 34         raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
     35     return res_values
     36 

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and Timestamp
```

This error comes from this column in my code:

```
#market opens 14:30 closes 21:00
def getAvgPerPrice (tweets,stockk):
    stock = stockk.copy()
    result = pd.DataFrame([]) 
    for i in range(0,len(stock)-1):
        d = stock.index[i]
        next_d = stock.index[i+1]
        wanted_tweets = tweets[((tweets.post_date - timedelta(hours = 3)) >=( d + timedelta(hours = h))) & ((tweets.post_date - timedelta(hours = 3)) < (next_d + timedelta(hours = h)))]
        result.at[i,'date'] = d
        result.at[i,'close'] = stock.iloc[i].Close
        result.at[i,'avgScore'] = wanted_tweets['score'].mean()
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me find the issue. I have tried many things already but no luck. Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like it could be an issue on what gets saved into the stock list. Either that or the result object is the wrong type. Cant see what's in those lists but I can see that one is tz-naive and the other is tz-aware. Make sure you have identical timezone objects in there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68506942/invalid-comparison-between-dtype-datetime64ns-utc-and-timestamp  and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093222/invalid-comparison-between-dtype-datetime64ns-and-timestamp   (They were the first two hits when I searched for `Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and Timestamp`)

Comment: Thank you. I tried to check the time stamps and converted both to same datetime64[ns]. It seems like i still get the same issue